# Upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 Broke Texstudio/Qt

Tags: ubuntu, qt, dist-upgrade, texstudio

After performing a dist upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 texstudio no longer runs. I get the following error

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I suspect the issue lies with texstudio configuration as the path is "" at the end of the first line of the error.

If I run `ldd /usr/bin/texstudio` I get

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1f53d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f64914f2000)
    libquazip5.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquazip5.so.1 (0x00007f64912c4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f64910a7000)
    libhunspell-1.6.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.6.so.0 (0x00007f6490e38000)
    libpoppler-qt5.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-qt5.so.1 (0x00007f6490bbf000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f6490950000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f6490109000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f648f9a0000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f648f614000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007f648f3d8000)
    libQt5Script.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Script.so.5 (0x00007f648ef42000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f648e7f7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f648e5d8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f648e24f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f648deb1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f648dc99000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f648d8a8000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f648d680000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f648d47c000)
    libpoppler.so.73 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73 (0x00007f648cfe8000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f648cd5c000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f648cb2a000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f648c88c000)
    libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f648c3eb000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f648c034000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007f648be23000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f648bb0d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6492612000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f648b909000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f648b703000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f648b44f000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f648b20a000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f648afa2000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f648ac5e000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0x00007f648aa32000)
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f648a7f5000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007f648a59d000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f648a326000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f648a0f5000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f6489e3f000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f6489c12000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f6488069000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f6487df7000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f6487be2000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f64879b0000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f6487781000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f648757c000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f6487378000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6487170000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f6486f4a000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f6486d3c000)
```

if I run `qtchooser -print-env` I get

```
qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

And the contents of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser` is

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     50 Dec 22  2017 4.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     50 Dec 22  2017 5.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     50 Dec 22  2017 qt4.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     50 Dec 22  2017 qt5.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
```

So it looks like qt is defaulting to qt4 but texstudio needs qt5. So i ran
`ln -s qt5.conf default.conf` in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser and now `qtchooser -print-env` prints

```
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

However, this does not resolve the issue. Texstudio still won't start and prints the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [grub bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1772900) reported for these exact symptoms. Following links in the comments i found the following [Virtualbox ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17425?cversion=0&cnum_hist=3) where another user posted the fix below

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5dbus5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5gui5 libqt5core5a libdouble-conversion1 libxcb-xinerama0`

Essentially, this bug resulted in packages being flagged as installed when they were not.